# 1970s story (perhaps made into a movie) about radioactive orphans raised by robots

Tags: story-identification

This is about a group of children (orphans, most likely), which have become radioactive and who are raised by/cared for by robots from their birth. I just remember one scene, where the protagonist, an adult white male, is guided by a young white boy, 10-13 years old, to some remote facility (where the children live) on a barren island near its coast. The coast is barren black rocks, kind of impossible to walk around on. He sees the boy open the outer door by using his hand as a key in front of a photo sensitive cell, which opens because the boys body is radioactive. Inside, the white man sees a robot.

Time frame: 1970s

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217892/sci-fi-film-similar-to-village-of-the-damned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible this is [*The Children of Light*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1040921) (1960) by H. L. Lawrence?

A man, fleeing the authorities, stumbles on a secret base on a military reservation where children with a high level of intrinsic radioactivity are being raised.

It was made into a 1963 movie [*The Damned*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Damned_(1963_film)).

Comment: i am trying to watch that very movie but it doesnt seem like the one. I will let you know when i  finished.

Comment: that was it.. However, i was disappointed. my memory betrayed me, as per usual.